# Android CountDownTimer is not getting cancel

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have created a countdown timer for 5 mins but if user complete the task in 2 mins i want to stop the timer.

I am using a boolean flag to check weather user complete the task or not.

If user completed the task before total time then i am calling `cancel()`

**My Code**

```
 public void settimer(final TextView time, long milliseconds) {

        new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setText(String.format("%d:%d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                AppController.RunningTime = millisUntilFinished;
                if (AppController.Stoptimer)
                    this.cancel();
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                AppController.TimeFinished = true;
            }

        }.start();
    }
```

`cancel()` is countdown timmer methods  [mentioned here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

[image]

`cancel()` is getting called but countdown timmer is not getting stop.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `AppController`?

Comment: @Vucko its Application Class.

Comment: First time I see it. It is supposed to be used as some kind of global variable? I'd recommend using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this kind of thing, it's perfect. If a user decides to cancel the timer, just post the appropriate event and onReceive of that event cancel the timer.

Comment: thanks @Vucko i will look on EventBus to fix this.

Comment: according to your code every time user calls to settimer() you're instantiation a new object of CountDownTimer. Now, maybe you have raise condition? like you accidently create more then 1 CountDownTimer then stops only one of them while the other keep running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int adsInterval = 3000;
CountDownTimer mTimer = mTimer = new CountDownTimer(adsInterval, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.d("Seconds", adsInterval + " second");
        // YOUR TASK
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
    }

};
mTimer.start();


Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}, 3000);
```

> To START Timer

```
mTimer.start();
```

> To STOP Timer

```
mTimer.cancel();
```